# wget `--reject-regex` not working?

Tags: regex, download, wget

Why is the following command able to download `index.html` from `www.example.com`?

`wget --reject-regex .* http://www.example.com/`

```
$ wget --reject-regex .* http://www.example.com/
--2018-03-05 11:21:26--  http://.keystone_install_lock/
Resolving .keystone_install_lock... failed: nodename nor servname provided, or not known.
wget: unable to resolve host address ‘.keystone_install_lock’
--2018-03-05 11:21:26--  http://www.example.com/
Resolving www.example.com... 93.184.216.34
Connecting to www.example.com|93.184.216.34|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 1270 (1.2K) [text/html]
Saving to: ‘index.html’

index.html                                                    100%[=================================================================================================================================================>]   1.24K  --.-KB/s    in 0s

2018-03-05 11:21:27 (4.49 MB/s) - ‘index.html’ saved [1270/1270]

FINISHED --2018-03-05 11:21:27--
Total wall clock time: 0.4s
Downloaded: 1 files, 1.2K in 0s (4.49 MB/s)
```

The man page of `wget` says

> --accept-regex urlregex
>
> --reject-regex urlregex
>
> Specify a regular expression to accept or reject the complete URL.

and the regular expression `.*` matches everything. (You may verify this using [freeformatter.com](https://www.freeformatter.com/regex-tester.html))

I think that everything `wget` downloads will be rejected because of `--reject-regex .*` option.

`.*` matches `www.example.com`, doesn't it?

Why doesn't wget ignore everything in `www.example.com`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`--regect-regex` will only reject URL links, not markup text in `index.html`. For example, if the website contains a URL to a CSS file `main.css` then this command will recursively download the website but exlude `main.css`:

```
wget -r --reject-regex 'main.css' www.somewebsite.com
```

To ignore some text from the website use `sed`. A couple of examples:

```
# Ignores the word 'Sans'
wget -qO- example.com | sed "s/Sans//g" > index.html

# Ignores everything
wget -qO- example.com | sed "s/.*//g" > index.html
```

Comment: So why is `www.example.com` not being rejected by `.*`? `www.example.com` is an URL link, isn't it?

Comment: Because `--reject-regex '.*'` will reject all URLs in `www.example.com` . It will not reject all text in `www.example.com`. In other words, `--reject-regex` only rejects URLs in a given website, not the actual text of the website.

Answer (score 1):

Part of the answer is that the `.*` in your command was likely expanded by your shell into a list of matching file names in your current working directory, because it isn't enclosed in appropriate quotes.  The `.keystone_install_lock` in the output that you got is likely the name of a file in your current working directory.  wget reports it before it even tries to connect to [www.example.com](http://www.example.com).  Try

```
wget --reject-regex '.*' http://www.example.com/
```

or perhaps with `""` instead of `''`, depending on which shell you're using.

With that command I still get index.html retrieved, so my answer isn't complete.

With `-np` as suggested by Quantum7 I still get index.html, so that doesn't complete the answer, either.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `-np` option to reject the index file. `--reject-regex` only applies to the recursive files (any links from the index file).

```
   -np
   --no-parent
       Do not ever ascend to the parent directory when retrieving recursively.
       This is a useful option, since it guarantees that only the
       files below a certain hierarchy will be downloaded.
```